# Adding VC++ project type support to Visual Studio 2010 after SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, service-pack

I have VS2010 Ultimate on a Win7 x32 machine up and running. I have installed VS2010 SP1 to this environment. Also have LightSwitch, Async CTP, etc installed.

Now, I find my self in a situation where I need to work on a VC++ project type. I ran the setup from the VS2010 DVD and chose to add features and selected VC++ and BAM!

[image: VS2010 VC++ issue]

I cant seem to get over this particular issue. I tried from App/Remove programs as well and tried the SP1 setup there but that's just for uninstalling VS2010 SP1. Anyone with similar experience?

Comment: Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Nope. Full uninstall and full reinstall. Sad, Long, unproductive, and always works :(